# Why do these two regular expressions work differently with re.sub(), but return the same match with re.search()?

Tags: python, python-re

Both regex are fetching same match but why does `",([\d-]+)"` work as expected and not the `"(,\d*-?\d*-?\d*)"`? I was expecting both regex to give me same output during `re.sub()`. What am I missing?

```py
>>> print(re.search(r",([\d-]+)", "Sabrina Green,802-867-5309,System Administrator"))       
<re.Match object; span=(13, 26), match=',802-867-5309'>
>>> print(re.search(r"(,\d*-?\d*-?\d*)", "Sabrina Green,802-867-5309,System Administrator"))       
<re.Match object; span=(13, 26), match=',802-867-5309'>
>>> 
>>> print(re.sub(r",([\d-]+)", r",+1-\1", "Sabrina Green,802-867-5309,System Administrator"))      
Sabrina Green,+1-802-867-5309,System Administrator
>>> print(re.sub(r"(,\d*-?\d*-?\d*)", r",+1-\1", "Sabrina Green,802-867-5309,System Administrator"))
Sabrina Green,+1-,802-867-5309,+1-,System Administrator
>>>
```

Expected output: `Sabrina Green,+1-802-867-5309,System Administrator`

Comment: One *includes* the comma in the capture group `\1`, while the other *excludes* it. Ignoring the differences in how many hyphens these regexes allow.

Comment: Seems like your second pattern is a little broken – you include the leading comma in the capture group (which you don't in the first pattern), and you're accepting empty strings of digits (which you don't in the first pattern). Maybe something like `r",(\d+-?\d+-?\d+)"` would be better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your regex string.
First, your comma is inside the parethesis, thus `,+1-,802-867-5309`

Second, you should replace the `*` with `+` in your regex. Notice the `5309,+1-,System Administrator`

In the future if you're having trouble with regex. You can check out [this site](https://extendsclass.com/regex-tester.html#python). It will break down the regex and give you a visual representation of what you're regex is doing.